# Extend ReSharper surround template with standard command

Tags: asp.net, resharper, resharper-7.1, live-templates

I have this asp.net surround ReSharper template:

```
<%:"$SELSTART$$SELECTION$$SELEND$"%>
```

Its adds <%: %> around the selected text and selects the text. The reason that I re-select the text is that I want to move it to the resource file afterwords, using <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

This means that I need to use the keys: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then hit the shorthand number key and then hit <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to move it to the resource. 
Is there anyway that I can combine the two commands?

I marked some text and hit some keys and it just surrounds the text with the response.write shorthand and add it to the resource file.

PS:
I'm using ReSharper 7.1